# how do you check load balancer method "algorithm" for a nginx ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, ingress, bare-metal, k3s

I do have an ingress controller load balancer in my Kubernetes Cluster, how do I know if my load balancer run which algorithm? and what happens if my load balancer is not working or the algorithm is not working properly.

Nb: install ingress controller from bitnami/ingress-controller and i run it in kubernetes cluster virtual machine without cloud sever( Bare metal)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default nginx ingress works on **round robin algorithm**. You can change its behavious by using different anotations.

ref:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-load-balancing